# Is "terroir" never translated?

Tags: word-usage, loanwords

It seems that *terroir* is always used in English as the original in French. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terroir) proposes a somewhat vague translation:

> Terroir can be very loosely translated as "a sense of place"

But is there another word/expression that is also used in place of *terroir* itself?

Comment: A quick google indicates *terrior* appears on several lists of "untranslatable terms" composed by a variety of different parties.  When used for its technical sense (i.e. when discussing the niceties of vineyards, vintages, artisanal cheeses, etc) the word is used verbatim, even in English texts.

Comment: Terroir: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/terroir. It is a term used mainly with reference to 'wine production', that's why the French term fits so well. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/terroir

Comment: Logic would seem to call for *earthiness*, but that means a whole different thing. *Locale?*, but that seems so vague?

Comment: Everything can be translated (otherwise English speakers wouldn't know what terroir means), just not necessarily exactly. You can use some English words in its place, they just may not be perfect. 'Land', 'the territory', 'the locale', 'the region', others I'm sure could work good enough.

Comment: It's translated into English as 'terroir'. Because there was no equivalent term, English has adopted the French term as a loan-word. **It's now part of the English lexicon.** There is even an alternative anglicised pronunciation available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is no alternative 'English' term to [terroir](http://www.discoverbeaujolais.com/community/terroir-a-wine-term-you-should-know/#) given its specific connotations:

> - If you ask a French person to translate the word terroir, their first response will likely be a long pause and a furrowed brow. Not because they’re unfamiliar with the term, ***but because there’s no word for it in English. Translating terroir requires the use of complete sentences.***
> - First things first: ***the etymology of the word. Terroir comes from terra, Latin for earth. Three core components of terroir are the vine, soil, and climate that produce a grape***. But these are only the material aspects.
> - ***As important is the abstract side of terroir, which is the belief that the combination of the vine, soil, and climate found in a particular plot of land will produce a grape that is unique to that plot.***

(www.discoverbeaujolais.com)

- Its usage has considerably increased in recent decades as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=terroir%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cterroir%3B%2Cc0).

From:  [The Science of Wine: From Vine to Glass](https://books.google.it/books?id=9hCk1J_5ozIC&pg=PA25&dq=%22terroir%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAWoVChMIjKvf3KTtxgIVRuFyCh1u6wFt#v=onepage&q=%22terroir%22&f=false)
 by Jamie Goode

> - "Terroir" is a concept that is rapidly emerging as the unifying concept of fine wine. Once almost exclusively the preserve of the Old World, it's now a talking point in the New World, too.

Comment: If you ask a Frenchman what *terroir* means, he will patiently explain that it means an [*Ensemble des terres d'une région, considérées du point de vue de leurs aptitudes agricoles et fournissant un ou plusieurs produits caractéristiques, par exemple un vin.*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/terroir/77475?q=terroir#76563) I am certain that that definition will prove no problem for further interpretation be it via translation ou non. You will note, however, that there is no French synonym for it in a single word either, and so I do not see the issue under discussion.

Comment: @tchrist - the issue is: is there an English synonym for terroir?

Comment: @tchrist Asking for a definition is different from asking for a translation

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say it is NEVER translated but in 40 years of reading about wine I have noticed that it is almost always explained to the English reader. To me that suggests that the wine experts have no corresponding English word.

Answer (score 1):

I started reading about oysters to think on this.  Turns out they're calling it *merroir*! Amusing.

In any event,

[***environment***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/environment) -

> 1. the aggregate of surrounding things, conditions, or influences; surroundings; milieu.
> 2. the air, water, minerals, organisms, and all other external factors surrounding and affecting a given organism at any time.

The issue, though, is that *terrior* is used to mean the qualities in the wine resulting specifically from environmental factors.  So perhaps "environmental traits," but there's a reason English speakers are using *terroir* as well.  It's pithy.  Environess? Environessence? Stick with *terroir*, especially if soil has anything to do with it.